# Render Django formset as array

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, nested-forms, formsets

I have a model and i need to create form with multiple instances in it. To be more specific: i need to render my ModelForm inside regular form with square brackets next to it's fields names. Something like this in magicworld:

**forms.py**

```
class ManForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Man
        fields = ['name', 'age']

class PeopleForm(forms.Form):
    # modelless form
    people = ??? # array of ManForm instances or something
```

**form.html**

```
<form action="/people/create/">
    {{ form }}
</form>
```

**output**

```
<form action="/people/create/">
    <input type="text" name="name[0]"/>
    <input type="text" name="age[0]"/>
</form>
```

To tell you the truth, i don't know how to approach this problem at all. I tried `modelformset_factory`, but all i've got is `<input type="text" name="form-0-name"/>`

Comment: Can you explain why you think you need that specific format, rather than the one that Django formsets use?

Comment: i need to iterate over each man in `view.py` and perform specific task

Comment: Yes, that is what a formset does. So why can't you use one?

Comment: it seems that i don't know how to iterate over formsets in view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you need a formset.

```
def create_people(request):
    PeopleFormSet = modelformset_factory(Man, form=ManForm)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = PeopleFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset:
                ... do something with individual form
    else:
        formset = PeopleFormSet()
    return render(request, template_name, {'formset': formset}
```

Comment: I didn't know that request.POST parses formsets that way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For using formsets in function based views see @Daniel Roseman 's answer or read up [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/#using-a-formset-in-views-and-templates).

For class based views there is no built in generic view for this. According to [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16256) they decided to let third-party-packages handle that. You can use [django-extra-views](https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views) for that.